# How to map one to many?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

Simplified question is that I have array `['a', 'b', 3, 'c']` and I want to change `3` with `null, null, null` like this `['a', 'b', null, null, null, 'c']` how can I do it with Ramda?

this is my full code

```js
const R = require('ramda')

const getBoardStateFromBoardString = R.pipe(
    R.split(''),
    R.map(
        R.cond([
            [
                R.test(/[bfmterk]/),
                R.assoc('piece', R.__, { color: 'b' })
            ],
            [
                R.test(/[BFMTERK]/),
                R.assoc('piece', R.__, { color: 'w' })
            ],
            [
                R.test(/\d/),
                R.pipe(
                    R.assoc('padding', R.__, {}),
                    R.evolve({ padding: parseInt })
                )
            ],
            [
                R.equals('/'),
                R.always({ padding: 8 })
            ]
        ])
    ),
)

console.log(getBoardStateFromBoardString('rmtektmr/8/bbbbbbbb/8/8/BBBBBBBB/8/RMTKETMR'))
```

result

```
[
  { color: 'b', piece: 'r' },
  { color: 'b', piece: 'm' },
  { color: 'b', piece: 't' },
  { color: 'b', piece: 'e' },
  { color: 'b', piece: 'k' },
  { color: 'b', piece: 't' },
  { color: 'b', piece: 'm' },
  { color: 'b', piece: 'r' },
  { padding: 8 },
  { padding: 8 },
  { padding: 8 },
  { color: 'b', piece: 'b' },
  ...
]
```

What I want is to map single **{ padding: 8 }** to **8 null** like this...

```
[
  { color: 'b', piece: 'r' },
  { color: 'b', piece: 'm' },
  { color: 'b', piece: 't' },
  { color: 'b', piece: 'e' },
  { color: 'b', piece: 'k' },
  { color: 'b', piece: 't' },
  { color: 'b', piece: 'm' },
  { color: 'b', piece: 'r' },

  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,

  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,

  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,

  { color: 'b', piece: 'b' },
  ...
]
```

So I wrote code that I want without Ramda like this...

```js
function getBoardStateFromBoardString(boardString) {
    const boardState = Array(128)
    let i = 0
    for (const symbol of boardString) {
        if (/[bfmterk]/.test(symbol)) {
            boardState[i] = {
                piece: symbol,
                color: 'b'
            }
            i++
        } else if (/[BFMTERK]/.test(symbol)) {
            boardState[i] = {
                piece: symbol,
                color: 'w'
            }
            i++
        } else if (/\d/.test(symbol)) {
            i += parseInt(symbol, 10)
        } else if (symbol === '/') {
            i += 8
        }
    }

    return boardState
}
```

But I have no idea how to do with Ramda (with point-free style if possible)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use R.chain to iterate the array items, and flatten the results. If an item is a number, use repeat to create an array of `null` values.

```js
const { chain, when, is, repeat } = R

const fn = chain(when(is(Number), repeat(null)))

const arr = ['a', 'b', 3, 'c']

const result = fn(arr)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.0/ramda.js"></script>
```

In your case, you can use R.cond with R.chain, and replace the creation of a padding object with repeated `null`:

```js
const { pipe, split, chain, cond, test, applySpec, identity, always, equals, repeat } = R

const getBoardStateFromBoardString = pipe(
  split(''),
  chain(
    cond([
      [
          test(/[bfmterk]/),
          applySpec({
            piece: identity,
            color: always('b')
          })
      ],
      [
          test(/[BFMTERK]/),
          applySpec({
            piece: identity,
            color: always('w')
          })
      ],
      [
          test(/\d/),
          repeat(null)
      ],
      [
          equals('/'),
          always(repeat(null, 8))
      ]
    ])
  ),
  
)

const result = getBoardStateFromBoardString('rmtektmr/8/bbbbbbbb/8/8/BBBBBBBB/8/RMTKETMR')

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.0/ramda.js"></script>
```

Comment: Wow, it works like a charm. I stuck to this problem for hours. I ran out of keywords to search on google. Tutorial on many websites don't mention R.chain. And also I have no idea how to create new object beautifully, so you save my life with R.applySpec. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome :) You would usually see this use case of R.chain as flatmap.